# Fix SearchView line

Tags: android, android-studio, search, android-activity

> Please help, I have been stuck for two days
> My project is somewhat complicated, and I could not add the search. I have main and submenus and I want to search all So
> What should be the ArrayAdapter I tried to put all the content and it didn't work
> **What do I put so that I can search?**

## search code line

```
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<List_itme>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_type);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_searchable);      
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("sarvhView");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

## MianActivity class

```
    ListView listView;
ArrayList<List_itme> list_itmes = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<List_itme> arrayAdapter;


String list_type = "main_index";

String Book_id;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private static long time;

TextView textView_Title,textViewto;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.maine_nav);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.openNavDrawer,
            R.string.closeNavDrawer

    );

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);










    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Index("index.txt");

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (list_type.equals("sub_index")){
        Index("index.txt");
        list_type="main_index";

        onResume();
    } else {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (time + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.Click_again_to_close, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

      

            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}


public void Index(String index_type) {
    list_itmes.clear();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(index_type);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String line ;
        int id=0;
        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            id++;
            list_itmes.add(new List_itme(line,"book_"+id)); //اسم الفولدر للمجلد الفرعي

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(list_itmes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           



    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}




class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<List_itme>list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<List_itme> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view1 = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_itme,null);
        TextView Title = view1.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Title.setText((CharSequence) list.get(i).getTitle());

        Typeface typefaces = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font1.ttf");
        Title.setTypeface(typefaces);


        Title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (list_type.equals("main_index")){ list_type="sub_index";
                    Book_id = list.get(i).getFolder_id();

                    Index(list.get(i).getFolder_id() + "/index.txt");//اسم الفهرس الفرعي

                }else if(list_type.equals("sub_index")) {//هذا لانتقال الفهرس الفرعي الى صفحة الويب

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Web_Activity.class);
                    String line ;
                    int id=0;
                    id++;
                    intent.putExtra("link",Book_id+"/html/"+i+".htm");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });



        return view1;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);






       /////////////////////////SearchView////////////////////////////////////
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<List_itme>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_type);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_searchable);      
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("search");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
///////////////////////////SearchView////////////////////////////////

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.help) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("help.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
                msg.append(line + "\n");
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            build.setTitle(R.string.help);
            build.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            build.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(msg + ""));
            build.setNegativeButton(R.string.dilog_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Negative
                }
            }).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.Close) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: `I want to search all`, So you need to create a custom adapter

Comment: Just a search engine, man

Comment: Is there anyone here please and please help me